# Metaclass constructor overriding not working for a method inside of @CompileStatic annotated class

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, metaprogramming, spock

When we use `someClass.metaClass.constructor` for any specific class (like [`RESTClient`](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/RESTClient)) available inside the method of a class which is annotated with `@CompileStatic`, constructor overriding is not working at all.

When we removed the `@CompileStatic` annotation, this works properly. Am I missing something?

Sample Code:

```
@CompileStatic
class FooClass {

    String getDataFromProvider() {
        String url = "https://www.example.com"
        RESTClient restClient = new RESTClient(url)

        HttpResponseDecorator response = restClient.post([:]) as HttpResponseDecorator
        return response
    }
}
```

And the test case:

```
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseDecorator
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import spock.lang.Specification

class FooContentSpec extends Specification {

    void "test getDataFromProvider method"() {
        given: "Rest url"
        String restURL = "https://www.example.com"

        and: "Mock RESTClient"
        RESTClient mockedRestClient = Mock(RESTClient)

        // THIS IS NOT WORKING
        RESTClient.metaClass.constructor = { Object url ->
            assert restURL == url
            return mockedRestClient
        }

        mockedRestClient.metaClass.post = { Map<String, ?> args ->
            return ""
        }

        when: "We hit the method"
        HttpResponseDecorator response = Content.getDataFromProvider()

        then: "We should get status 200"
        response.statusCode == 200
    }
}
```

According to the [Groovy Lang](https://groovy-lang.org/testing.html#_mockfor_and_stubfor) doc:

> `MockFor` and `StubFor` can not be used to test statically compiled classes e.g for Java classes or Groovy classes that make use of `@CompileStatic`. To stub and/or mock these classes you can use Spock or one of the Java mocking libraries.

#### Expected Behaviour

In this scenario, constructor overriding of `RESTClient` should work in our test cases because we don't want to hit third party API in every test case.

#### Actual Behaviour

Unfortunately, `RESTClient` does not get mocked because of `@CompileStatic` annotation it hits the API every time.

#### Environment Information

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Groovy:       2.4.10,
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015,
JVM:          1.8.0_221 (Oracle Corporation 25.221-b11),
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.2 x86_64
```

Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9353

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right `@CompileStatic` cannot be used in conjunction with metaclass manipulation. The reason is that, as the name suggest, all is resolved and bound at compile time, so there are no metaclass lookups, and so no way to override this.

I'd suggest looking into IoC/dependency injection, so that you can just inject the mock into your code. Working with classical singletons makes your code way harder to test.

Comment: A nice suggestion about using DI but the `@CompileStatic` is used in another class while we are trying to override the constructor of a different class which is being used in the first class. So that should also matter?

Comment: Yes `@CompileStatic` will resolve the constructor of `RESTClient` in your `FooClass` at compile time so it will not use the metaclass to lock it up at runtime. If you want to see how it looks, I'd suggest using a decompiler, e.g. ByteCode viewer and look at the generated bytecode.

Comment: Correct, I missed the compile-time constructor thing. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

After the comment from [Leonard Brünings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2145769/leonard-br%c3%bcnings):

> Yes @CompileStatic will resolve the constructor of RESTClient in your FooClass at compile time so it will not use the metaclass to lock it up at runtime. If you want to see how it looks, I'd suggest using a decompiler, e.g. ByteCode viewer and look at the generated bytecode.

We decompiled the generated byte code for two scenarios:

#### With `@CompileStatic`

```
public class FooClass implements GroovyObject {
    public FooClass() {
        MetaClass var1 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = var1;
    }

    public String getDataFromProvider() {
        String url = "https://www.example.com";

        // Directly constructor is getting used
        RESTClient restClient = new RESTClient(url);

        HttpResponseDecorator response = (HttpResponseDecorator)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(restClient.post(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createMap(new Object[0])), HttpResponseDecorator.class);
        return (String)ShortTypeHandling.castToString(response);
    }
}
```

#### Without `@CompileStatic`

```
public class FooClass implements GroovyObject {
    public FooClass() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        super();
        MetaClass var2 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = var2;
    }

    public String getDataFromProvider() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        String url = "https://www.example.com";

        // Here Groovy's metaprogramming is into play instead of directly calling constructor
        RESTClient restClient = (RESTClient)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var1[0].callConstructor(RESTClient.class, url), RESTClient.class);

        HttpResponseDecorator response = (HttpResponseDecorator)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.asType(var1[1].call(restClient, ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createMap(new Object[0])), HttpResponseDecorator.class);
        return (String)ShortTypeHandling.castToString(response);
    }
}
```

So the answer given by @Leonard is totally correct. We missed this simple Java concept.