# Cannot mock static Groovy method when using '@CompileStatic'

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, spock

I'm trying to mock a static helper class (`ConfigHelper`) which returns config values. This has worked before in many other tests, but fails in my newest Spock test for some reason.

The service I'm testing is the following:

```
<redacted>
import grails.plugin.cache.Cacheable
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct

@CompileStatic
class AssetsIntegrationService extends ExternalDiagnosticService {

    static String urlTilErstLogo() {
        return ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.ERST_LOGO_URL)
    }

    @Cacheable(value = 'erst-logo')
    String hentErstLogoSomBase64Streng() {
        String url = urlTilErstLogo()  // returns null
        String url2 = ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.ERST_LOGO_URL) // returns null
        return getByteArrayFromImageURL(url)
    }

    private static String getByteArrayFromImageURL(String url) {
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url)
        URLConnection ucon = imageUrl.openConnection()
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream()
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]
        int read = 0
        while ((read = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            baos.write(buffer, 0, read)
        }
        baos.flush()
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(baos.toByteArray())
    }
}
```

And my spock test:

```
<redacted>
import grails.testing.gorm.DataTest
import grails.testing.services.ServiceUnitTest
import spock.lang.Specification

class AssetsIntegrationServiceSpec extends Specification implements DataTest, ServiceUnitTest<AssetsIntegrationService>{

    def setup() {
        GroovyMock(ConfigHelper, global: true)
        ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.ERST_LOGO_URL) >> "https://url.com"
    }

    def "hentErstLogoSomBase64Streng"() {
        when:
            String res = service.hentErstLogoSomBase64Streng()
        then:
            noExceptionThrown()
    }
}
```

It seems like my mock is ignored, because `ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.ERST_LOGO_URL)` simply returns null in my service. However, if I set a breakpoint in the service and try calling `ConfigHelper.hentConfig(ConfigNoegler.ERST_LOGO_URL)` from the IntelliJ expression evaluator, the correct mocked url is retured!

Comment: Try removing `@CompileStatic` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59481265/2145769 for details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by `@CompileStatic` just remove it, or replace it by `@TypeChecked`.

It is the same problem I've explained here already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59481265/2145769